# How can I put a subscript in a special symbol with a dot or a hat

Tags: math-mode, accents

I have this symbol: `${q_{\alpha}}$`, but I don't know how put a dot or a hat in the letter "q". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the accent *first*, then the subscript:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$q_\alpha \quad
 \hat{q}_\alpha \quad
 \dot{q}_\alpha$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend.